# Profiling iOS web app with Safari has no profiles

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I've been looking at profiling an iOS application (WKWebView) with Safari. I've used the Timelines section and gotten a bunch of records. The problem is that the record content is completely useless. It basically just says that I have a bunch of events, which were listened to by jQuery, that took a long time to finish.

It doesn't state why that's actually the case at all, or show the time spent in the call tree (or show the call tree at all).

How can I convince Safari to actually profile the javascript involved instead of just telling me that it is slow?